# Having trouble outputting dataSource values onto table in angular from calling api request

Tags: html, angular, typescript, datasource

```
Component File
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppointmentService } from '../appointments.service';
import { Appointment } from '../Appointment';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-appointment-list',
  templateUrl: './appointment-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appointment-list.component.css']
})


export class AppointmentListComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public loading = true;
  public errorMsg!: string | "Sorry there was an error performing this action";
  public successMsg!: string | "Success!";
  public columns: string[] = ['appointmentDate','appointmentTime', 'name', 'email', 'cancel'];
  public appointments: Appointment[] = [];
  public index = ["_id", "appointmentDate", "appointmentTime", "name", "email"];
  public dataSource!: Appointment[];

  constructor(private appointmentService: AppointmentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appointmentService.getAppointments()
      .subscribe((appointments: Appointment[]) => {
        this.appointments =  appointments;
        this.loading = false;
        this.dataSource = appointments;
        console.log(this.dataSource[0].name);
        console.log(appointments);
      },
      (error: ErrorEvent) => {
        this.errorMsg = error.error.message;
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
  cancelAppointment(id: string) {
    this.appointmentService.cancelAppointment(id)
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(() => this.appointmentService.getAppointments())
      )
      .subscribe((appointments: Appointment[]) => {
        this.appointments = appointments;
        this.successMsg = 'Successfully cancelled appointment';
      },
      (error: ErrorEvent) => {
        this.errorMsg = error.error.message;
      });
  }


}



Component.html



<p>{{ appointments[3].appointmentDate }}</p>

<div *ngIf="!loading && !errorMsg">


    <table mat-table [dataSource]='dataSource' class="mat-elevation-z8">

        <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
              The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
      
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let appointment"> {{ appointment.name }} </td>

        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="appointmentDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Appointment Date </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let appointment"> {{ appointment.appointmentDate }} </td>


        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="appointmentTime">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Appointment Time </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let appointment"> {{ appointment.appointmentTime }} </td>



        </ng-container>

      
        <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Email </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let appointment"> {{ appointment.appointmentEmail }} </td>

        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="cancel">
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let appointment"><button mat-raised-button color="warn">Cancel</button></td>
        </ng-container>
      

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;"></tr>

</table>
</div>
```

I am getting the console log that I am using in the .ts file, but when I go map it on the table it isn't outputting anything on the table, or the table at all. I just need help outputting the values to the table, while looping through my appointment array of Appointment objects.
An example of the appointments array is:

---

[
{
"_id": "5fb571bd3362398ca5238adb",
"appointmentDate": "08/24/2019",
"appointmentTime": "10:00",
"name": "Jaime2",
"email": "test@gmail.com"
},
{
"_id": "5fbd65650ef8b8880d01d8ec",
"appointmentDate": "08/24/2020",
"appointmentTime": "10:00",
"name": "Jaime",
"email": "test@gmail.com"
}
]

[This is what the code amounts to, everything has been imported and the modules have been put in the right spots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJAB9.png)

Comment: try removing exclamation symbol from public dataSource!: Appointment[];

Comment: This has to be `public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Appointment>()` and then assign with `this.dataSource.data = appointments`.

Comment: @GunnarB. thank you that helped